# How to detect database type?

Tags: database, types, detection

I need to be sure the database I'm connecting to is MySQL and not PostgreSQL or Microsoft SQL Server.How can I find out which type of database is being used .

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?

Answer (score 4):

The first hint might be the "connection error" you're likely to get if you try to connect to a PostgreSQL database with a mySQL database driver :)

Basically, you need to:

1) Code your application in a portable manner (don't use MSSQL extensions in a query that might be run on mySql, for example)

2) Choose a portable driver API (like JDBC, ODBC, ADO.Net, etc)

3) Provide some mechanism for your application to query the actual database type at runtime (for example, an .config properties file)

4) Test your completed application against each of the supported database types.

'Hope that helps .. PSM

Comment: what if its already be connected ?, is there any query to find out this database is mysql ?

Comment: Dude - your application wouldn't already be connected if it didn't know the right database type in the first place.  Would it?  But in any case - most driver APIs (again: ODBC, JDBC, ADO.Net - all the usual suspects) usually have a mechanism to query details about the server you're connected to.

Comment: Is it me or he sounds like a mysql intruder/injection attempt?

Comment: you are right, thanks for help, yah, its injection attempt for educational purpose

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your comments, you have an SQL CLI-like interface or you can only execute SQL queries and you want to know if it's a mysql server answering your queries.

You could use

```
SELECT @@version_comment
```

which will return something like `MySQL Community Server` if it's a MySQL server

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the running database process on the host your trying to connect.

Example: 
ps -ef | grep mysql

Answer (score 0):

No dude! It is possible to connect to a database without knowing the database type. For ex. I am working for a vendor called xactly. They have their database links as xactly..com and jdbc as xactly.jdbc.com. I can connect fine to the instance using the driver but am still trying to find the database type